# How to detect browser width change and call all data table elements and tell them to resize?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am using the below code which is not working adjustColumnSizing throws an error-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var oTable = $('#tableID').dataTable({
       "sScrollY": "400px",
       "bPaginate": true,
       "bAutoWidth":false,
        } );

   $(window).on('resize', function () {
             oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
          } );
```

But I am supposed to use the following code to initialize my data table-

```
$('.table').not("#TableID").DataTable({
                  stateSave: true,            
                  columnDefs: [{
                   "targets": [7],
                   "visible": false
                       }, {
                   "targets": [8],
                  "visible": false
                       }]
                        });
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong as I am new to this

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you're just looking to adjust layout properties, like column widths, I'd recommend checking out  css @media rules. Using events and mutating the DOM directly can have unintended outcomes. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing is not a function . I also get this one- TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Simply use window resize event:

```
var previousWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
       if($(this).width() != previousWidth){
            //window width has been changed...
          //further action here...
       }
    });
```